# What is the most numerically stable method to find eigenvalues of a sparse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, algorithms, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I thought of using QR algorithm which uses QR decomposition with Gram-Schmidt process but I found that to be very numerically unstable. That is, the dot product of orthonormal sets aren't 0, but close to 0 like 0.004 or -.08

So, for given a large sparse real matrix, what is the most numerically stable 
(and most efficient) algorithm or methods to find the eigenpairs?

Comment: You should take a look at randomized matrix algorithms for finding "approximate" eigenvalue decompositions. These algorithms return low-rank approximations that only require a constant number of passes through your data. There is a *very* nice paper written by Halko, et al. (http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~jtropp/papers/HMT11-Finding-Structure-SIREV.pdf) which covers all of this in detail, and provides rigorous analysis of both aspects of computational complexity and error estimation.

Comment: Also, most of these algorithms aren't too hard to implement on your own!

Comment: Maybe power methods could work. They are nice in the sense that matrix-vector multiplication is usually very cheap (fast) for sparse matrices. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration